# mod_rewrite combine these two rules into one

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have two rules that currently function as they should, but I feel like they can be consolidated into one for the benefit of a smaller config to maintain and less rules to process for each HTTP request. The rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/user/[0-9]+/?$ /index.php [NC,QSA,L] 
RewriteRule ^/user/[0-9]+/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I had to add the first rule with an explicit redirect to `/index.php` because going to `http://www.example.com/user/5/`, for example, would give me an HTTP 400. The rewrite would internally rewrite to `/`, but instead of reading the DirectoryIndex, `index.php`, the error_log would give me: `client denied by server configuration: /`.

Adding the explicit redirect to `/index.php` fixed URLs such as `http://www.example.com/user/5/` and the second rule would work for everything else.

Is there a way to set the config to just normally use the `DirectoryIndex` I have set and not explicitly list index.php here? `http://www.example.com` works just fine without the rewrite rules, so I'm not entirely sure why a rewrite would break it.

Comment: Those really should be two rules. Of course, it's better still if your web application uses a front controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine these 2 rules. I think these rules are located in a VHost config file or another config file, but not in .htaccess, nor in a Directory section inside the VHost config. This means you are in a per server context.

**The problem:**

In per server context, the substitution (last part of the rewrite) can be a file system path or an URL.

Apache tries to guess if you meant an URL or a file system path. The [RewriteRule doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) states:

> Substitutions are only treated as a file-system path when the rule is
>   configured in server (virtualhost) context and the first component of
>   the path in the substitution is exists in the file-system

So your rule nr 2 rewrites everything that begins with /user/[0-9]/ to /. And now you can see that the path / (the path with no name) exists in the file system. But of course you have restricted access to that directory, so you have the `client denied`.

**The solutions:**

Remove the first rule, with the index.php and

Use the [PT flag (passthrough)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/user/[0-9]+/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,QSA,L,PT]
```

Or be more specific in your substitution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/user/[0-9]+/(.*)$ /root/and/full/path/to/www/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Hope this helps!